# $\int_a^b f(x)dx=\int_a^bg(x)dx$ (for arbitrary $a$ and $b$) implies $f(x)=g(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Let $f,g$ be functions defined over $\mathbb{R}$, such that
> $\int_a^bf(x)dx=\int_a^bg(x)dx$ for all $a,b \in \mathbb {R}$. How to
> prove this implies $f(x)=g(x)$?

I tried the following: let $h(x)$ be a primitive of $f(x)-g(x)$, then we have $\int_a^b f(x)-g(x)=0\Rightarrow \int_a^b h'(x)=0 \Rightarrow h(b)=h(a) \Rightarrow f(b)-g(b) = f(a)-g(a) \ \forall a,b$.

How to finish with this result from there?

Comment: Are $f$ and $g$ continuous?

Comment: @Infinity_hunter yes

Comment: The condition implies $\mathbf 1_{[a,b]}f-g = 0$. Since step functions are dense in $L^1$, you can identify $f$ with $g$ (as elements of $L^1$). If you also assume continuity, then $f\equiv g$

Comment: Suppose there were an $x$ such that $f(x)\neq g(x)$. Without loss of generality assume $f(x)>g(x)$. Then by continuity, there is a neighborhood $(a,b)$ of $x$ such that $f(x)> g(x)$, so that $\int_a^b f > \int_a^b g$

Comment: You're solution is on the right track - once you showed $h(a)=h(b)$, since $a,b$ were arbitrary, you can infer that $h$ is constant, therefore $h'=0$, and $f=g$.

Comment: @Amit that's it thank you

Comment: @DavidP are you assuming $f(x)>g(x)$ for all $x$?

Comment: I dont think even continuity is needed integrability should be enough dont quote on that though

Answer (score 1):

You also could define some function $F(x)=\int^x_a(f(x)-g(x))dx$ for some constant 'a' since F is constant over $\mathbb{R}$ $F'(x)=f(x)-g(x)=0$

Your solution is done at $h(a)=h(b)$ since it implies $h(a)=h(0)$ for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$